# (NodeJS) How to Validation in 'Routes' and send to 'Controller' [MVC]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, model-view-controller

i have a problem in my code:
*idols.js*

```
router.post(
'/creating',

check('name', 'Min 1 and Max 50!').isLength({ min: 1, max: 50 }),

(req, res) => {
  
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {      
    alertError = errors.array();
    res.render('idols/create', {alertError});      
  }
  else {  
    //Next if value is good
  }      
});
```

and idolsController.js

```
const idols = require('../models/idols'); 
class idolsController {

creating(req, res, next) {
    const idols_data = new idols(req.body);
    idols_data.save()
            .then(() => res.redirect('/idols/edit'))
            .catch(next());
}
module.exports = new idolsController;
```

my idols.js when not using logic validation

```
router.post('/creating', idolsController.creating);
```

--- My question:
I want to convert the code in the 3rd paragraph to the code in the 1st paragraph (in this topic)
thank for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Please review and update